# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "ORDER": syntax error (code 1): ,

Tags: android, sqlite

I keep getting this error.  I'm sure it's a simple syntax error.  Does anyone see it?  I been debugging for ~30min and can't seem to find it.

query

```
DELETE FROM SuccessfulCalls ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2
```

Actual code to insert to db.

```
SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper     = ApplicationClass.getSqLiteHelper();
SQLiteDatabase db             = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
String query = "DELETE FROM " + sqLiteHelper.SUCCESSFULCALLSTABLE + " ORDER BY " + sqLiteHelper.SUCCESSFULID + " DESC LIMIT " + Constants.NUMBEROFCALLSTODELETE ;
db.rawQuery(query, null);
db.close();
```

**UPDATE**
I have tried this query, but for some reason it does not delete the rows from my database.

```
DELETE FROM SuccessfulCalls WHERE id IN ( SELECT id FROM SuccessfulCalls ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5 );
```

But I know the query is getting executed because when I try.  It deletes my whole table. 
     DELETE FROM SuccessfulCalls

**UPDATE**
I was setting up my primary key wrong.  For sql lite to autoincrement one's primary key they need INTEGER PRIMARY KEY not int PRIMARY KEY

Comment: So, did you use `rawQuery()` or `execSQL()` for the updated query?

Comment: I tried both rawQuery() and execSQL().

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` are not syntactically allowed with a `DELETE` query unless [sqlite is built with `SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html) which is not the case on Android.

If you want to delete the two highest `id` rows, use

```
DELETE FROM SuccessfullCalls WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM SuccessfulCalls ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2);
```

Use `execSQL()` for such queries and not `rawQuery()` to get the SQL actually run.

Comment: @Strawberry Works for me. Care to explain the problem?

Comment: Note that in MySQL (as per the original tags), you cannot specify the target table in this way. Also, MySQL prohibits the use of LIMIT in a DELETE - even one wrapped inside a subquery.

Comment: It's also ok to use delete() not just execSQL()

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use ORDER BY in a DELETE statement. See http://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html

Comment: That page actually shows that ORDER BY can be used in a DELETE statement.

Comment: "If SQLite is compiled with the SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT compile-time option" -- this is not the case for Android.

Comment: This should be mentioned in the answer, because it's the cause of the problem.