# Unable to get datas from the past two months using sqlite query

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio, cursor

Im using the following code to fetch datas from the past two months.

```
 public List<String> getDates() {
        SQLiteDatabase db       = this.getReadableDatabase();
        List<String>   dateList = new ArrayList<>();

        String query = "SELECT DISTINCT " + KEY_PROGRESSDATE + " FROM " + TABLE_ENTRY + " WHERE progressdate >= date('now','start of month','-1 month') AND progressdate < date('now','start of month') desc";

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        if (c.getCount() > 0) {
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                dateList.add(c.getString(0));
            }
        }
        return dateList;
    }
```

But im getting the follwing error message..

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "desc":
>   syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT progressdate
>   FROM entry WHERE progressdate >= date('now','start of month','-1
>   month') AND progressdate < date('now','start of month') desc

why is that so?

Comment: Try thisSELECT DISTINCT progressdate FROM entry WHERE progressdate >= date('now','start of month','-1 month') AND progressdate < date('now','start of month') order by progressdate desc

Answer (score 2):

for this exception, you have to write `ORDER BY "Columname" DESC`

here, it will be like

```
SELECT DISTINCT progressdate FROM entry WHERE progressdate >= date('now','start of month','-1 month') AND progressdate < date('now','start of month') ORDER BY progressdate desc
```

check [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23936829/android-database-sqlite-sqliteexception-near-order-syntax-error-code-1)

Comment: can you please accept as answer if that solved your issue ?@Learner

Answer (score 0):

You're not using any Order By clause in query. Maybe you're trying to put  progressdate in descending order?

```
String query = "SELECT DISTINCT " + KEY_PROGRESSDATE + " FROM " + TABLE_ENTRY + " WHERE progressdate >= date('now','start of month','-1 month') AND progressdate < date('now','start of month') ORDER BY progressdate desc";
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey why to use the raw Query if functions are already there. Try below function to get values from any table just pass your parameters in it:

```
public String[] getValues(boolean b, String table, String column,
                              String where, String orderBy) {
        ArrayList<String> savedAns = new ArrayList<String>();
        Cursor result = null;
        String[] y;
        try {
            result = db.query(b, table, new String[]{column}, where, null,
                    null, null, orderBy, null);
            if (result.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    savedAns.add(result.getString(result.getColumnIndex(column)));
                } while (result.moveToNext());
            } else {
                return null;
            }
            y = savedAns.toArray(new String[result.getCount()]);
        } finally {
            result.close();
        }
        return y;
    }
```

Hope it helps you..